# How to extract a dynamic pattern from a command output after removing a couple of patterns using for loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, automation, operating-system

Using the first "for" loop to extract a specific line from the output, while want that extracted output to be further removed with certain patterned number of text, can you please assist on this..

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %i in ('dir /r ^| findstr -li "zone.id"') do @echo %i >> C:\zone.txt
```

the output of the above loop is like:

```
 26 789A44F9D1497937126FF305C6CB89D0.ics:Zone.Identifier:$DATA 
 29 active.csv:Zone.Identifier:$DATA 
 26 file trans today.jpg:Zone.Identifier:$DATA 
 26 BC of raji.pdf:Zone.Identifier:$DATA 
 29 modern - Contest 2016 Submission_updated 2019 - july-10.pdf:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
 26 mesge_mon_results (1).csv:Zone.Identifier:$DATA 
 26 [MS-DoCTS].pdf:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
```

i want to remove the space before and after 26 / 29 including the 2 digit number and :$DATA and get the output as below:

```
789A44F9D1497937126FF305C6CB89D0.ics:Zone.Identifier       
active.csv:Zone.Identifier        
file trans today.jpg:Zone.Identifier         
BC of raji.pdf:Zone.Identifier       
modern - Contest 2016 Submission_updated 2019 - july-10:Zone.Identifier       
mesge_mon_results (1).csv:Zone.Identifier      
[MS-DoCTS].pdf:Zone.Identifier
```

despite it can be easily done using the replace option in notepad, i like to automate this through batch script.

Comment: change `tokens=*` to `tokens=1*` and `echo %j`

Comment: Thank you Stephen for the comment, Tried this in between a series of attempts.. but still :$DATA stuck behind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Regex in vbscript with a batch file like this code : You can see [Regex Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/OpjL80/1)

```bat
@echo off
Mode 85,20 & color 0A
Title Replace String using Regex with vbscript
Set "InputFile=%~dp0zone.txt"
Set "OutPutFile=%~dp0New_Zone_After_Replacing.txt"
echo(
:: To show Results on screen of console
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" CON
:: To write Result in new file
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
echo(
echo Press any key to show the results in a new file :
echo "%OutPutFile%"
pause>nul
Start "" "%OutPutFile%" 
echo(
echo Did you want to update and replace all in your original file "%InputFile%" ?
Pause>nul
Move /Y "%OutPutFile%" "%InputFile%">nul
Start "" "%InputFile%" & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "\b(\d\d\s)(.*)(:\$DATA)"
    echo strReplace = "$2"
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

***EDIT : Using Regex with Powershell in a batch file :***

```bat
@echo off
Title Search and Replace with Powershell and batch
Set "InputFile=%~dp0zone.txt"
Set "OutPutFile=%~dp0New_zone.txt"
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Start "" "%OutPutFile%"
Exit
REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
Powershell ^
GC -path "%~1" ^| %% { $_ -Replace '\b(\d\d\s^)(.*^)(:\$DATA^)','$2' } ^| Out-File "%~2"
Exit /B
REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you Hackoo for the swift advice. I will try this.

Comment: Thank you Hackoo, the powershell based script works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a replacement to get rid of `:$DATA`. You'll need `delayedexpansion` however.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in ('dir /r ^| findstr /IRC:"zone\.id"') do (
    set "line=%%~j"
    echo !line::$DATA=!
 )
)>C:\zone.txt
```

You also do not need to use `delims= "` as whitespace is a default delimeter.

One more note, this would need to go into a batch file, not on `cmd`

If you require this to run from `cmd` and not from a batch file then from cmd activate `delayedexpansion` by running `cmd /V:ON` and use this line:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %i in ('dir /r ^| findstr /IRC:"zone\.id"') do set "line=%~j" & (echo !line::$DATA=!)>>C:\zone.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Gerhard for the correction and explanation.